# Exception Type: KeyError

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

В Api в некоторых полях нет данных {}. Из-за этого ругается на строчку `if sc[key][0]:`
Пишет:

> Exception Type:    KeyError Exception Value: 0

Как заменить чтобы при остуствии данных записывал знак `?` во многих полях где данные есть всё работает нормально.

```
def stats_as_json(self):
    sc=json.loads(self.statsJson)
    ret={'3points':{},'2points':{}}
    for key in ['3points','2points']:
        if not key in sc: continue;
        if sc[key][0]:
            ret[key]['home']=sc[key][0]
        if sc[key][1]:
            ret[key]['away']=sc[key][1] 
    return ret
```

`if isinstance(sc[key], list):`

Пробовал `.get` и `try exc`

JSON запрос к API:

```
default_stats = {'3points': {'home': '', 'away': ''},'2points': {'home': '', 'away': ''}}
```

и

```
statsJson=json.dumps({**default_stats, **(e.get('stats') or {})}),
```

Данные с API:

```
"stats":{"2points":["18","22"],"3points":["11","12"],
```

Comment: Если пустая строка, то вместо нее `?`? Т.е. например для `'3points': {'home': '', 'away': ''}` получится `'3points': {'home': '?', 'away': '?'}`

Comment: ничего не помогает. половина страниц работает нормально все отображается корректно; половина Key Error

Comment: А почему, тут у вас у `2points` и `3points'` находятся словари `{'3points': {'home': '', 'away': ''},'2points': {'home': '', 'away': ''}}`, а тут `{"2points":["18","22"],"3points":["11","12"]` списки? Мне непонятно, что из этого находится в `sc`. Давайте так, вы показываете в вопросе, что находится в `sc` и что должно получиться в `ret`, я помогаю с алгоритмом и с этим вопросом заканчиваем? :D Кст, вы не ответили на мой комментарий выше.

Answer (score 2):

> Как заменить чтобы при остуствии данных записывал знак "?"

Попробуйте:

```
def stats_as_json(self):
    sc = json.loads(self.statsJson)
    ret = {'3points': {}, '2points': {}}
    for key in ['3points','2points']:
        if key not in sc: continue
        ret[key]['home'] = sc[key].get('home') or "?"
        ret[key]['away'] = sc[key].get('away') or "?"
    return ret
```

Без привязки к конкретным ключам:

```
def stats_as_json(self):
    sc = json.loads(self.statsJson)
    ret = {'3points': {}, '2points': {}}
    for key in ['3points', '2points']:
        if key not in sc: continue
        for k, v in sc[key].items():
            ret[key][k] = v or "?"
    return ret
```

Comment: теперь пишет - Exception Value: 
'list' object has no attribute 'get'
AttributeError

Comment: @АлексейАверин, значит в `sc[key]` у вас список, а не словарь как было показано ошибкой в вопросе, т.к. `KeyError` относится только к словарям

Comment: и какое есть решение?

Comment: Разберитесь с тем какие данные у вас в `sc[key]`. Если словарь, то используйте `get`, если список, нужно проверять размер списка и заполнять в зависимости от наличия элементов (накидаю пример)

Comment: когда в API вот это - тогда все работает - "stats":{"2points":["18","22"],"3points":["11","12"],

если - "stats":{}, - страницы рушатся.

Comment: пробывал вариант со списком - итог: Exception Type: KeyError Exception Value: 
0
на строчку: ret[key]['home'] = sc[key][0]

Comment: Значит, что в тот момент у вас там был словарь :) Вы ведь не в слепую работаете с данными? Выводили их, проверяли что в `self.statsJson` находится? Я могу предложить костыль с проверкой типа в `sc[key]`, но это костыль, а значит возможны и другие приколы с данными :) Костыль: `if isinstance(sc[key], list): <код с try/except> else: <код с .get>`